# Swaggerhub integration in spring boot

Tags: swagger, swaggerhub

I am new to swaggerhub so please explain me from basics.

In our project we are using springfox swagger and need to generate swaggerhub api specification.

How can I achieve this? Please let me know in detail or share reference links.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little confusing. What do you mean by "swaggerhub api specification"?

Swagger is the documentation specification/tools used to work with the document spec. SwaggerHub is a design and collaboration tools for creating and maintaining Swagger documents.

SwaggerHub hosts Swagger documents, they work together rather than independently.

If you're creating Swagger documents and want to upload them to SwaggerHub automatically, you can do that using the SwaggerHub CLI or Registry API tools:
CLI: https://github.com/SmartBear/swaggerhub-cli
Registry API: https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis-docs/swagger-hub/registry-api/1.0.62